# Django How can I expand list into models without overwriting ID?

Tags: django-models, django-views

```py
#Model
class You(models.Model):
    Name = models.TextField(null=False)
    Age  = models.IntegerField(null=False)

# What i want to do
data = [["john", 16] ,["jax", 18]] 
for d in data:
    You(*d)
```

Then it tries to override id.

i set to `editable=False` but it can't help too

Any way to skip `id` field ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign it with *named* parameters:

```
# What i want to do
data = [['john', 16], ['jax', 18]]
for name, age in data:
    You(Name=name, Age=age)
```

Another option is to pass `DEFERRED` for the primary key, so:

```
from django.db.models import DEFERRED

for d in data:
    You(DEFERRED, *d)
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `age` instead of <s>`Age`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Specifying [**`null=False`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) is not necessary: fields are by default not NULLable.

Comment: Thanks for the deferred, gonna try. about the case I was writing on mobile phone . The actual array have 38 fields so didn't want to use named params.

Comment: Deferred dosn't work for me.